# hide tablayout and appbar using co-ordinator layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout, appbar

I have a main activity with a appbar layout(also containing a navigation view) and a fragment with a tablayout . I want the user to be able to hide and show both of them while scrolling  like Google Play Music app.But I just can't get the app bar to hide as it is not in the fragment although the tablayout is getting hidden fine.Also I can't move the appbar layout into the fragment as this will make my code for switching between fragments using navigation view very complicated.I am using coordinator layout for achieving this.How do I achieve this?.My code is as below-

WelcomeActivity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

       <include
        android:id="@+id/welcome_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/default_toolbar_layout"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_nav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/welcome_menu_drawer"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Myfragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/welcome_feeds_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/welcome_feeds_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/welcome_feeds_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton
    android:id="@+id/welcome_feeds_fab"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:button_color="@color/accent"
    app:image="@mipmap/add"
    app:image_size="24dp"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code yet.....
Is your tabLayout correctly swipe out the screen on scrolling? 
Have you tried to move inside CoordinatorLayout also the Toolbar?
To use the features by design Library all the elements have to be inside CoordinatorLayout and you have to set as your needs the correct property "app:layout_scrollFlags"

Comment: My tab layout swipes out of the screen on scolling.The problem is that the appbar or toolbar  does not hide or swipe out of the screen.Can you suggest anyway how to move the toolbar inside the coordinator layout? Can I use the fragment tag inside the welcome activity and move the coordinator away to the welcome activity.xml?Please tell me how to achieve it.Thank you.